# Why is div width not changing when browser window re-sizes?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a div named **body-container** .

I want to change the width of the div depending on the browser window size. I am using the **flexbox** model to do it, but the width is not changing according to the size of the browser window.

My CSS :

```
.body-container
{
    display:flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #A8A8A8;
    width:800px;
    height:250px;
}
```

Is there something I need to do with the margin of the divider or is there any other way to make the divider completely flexibly (width wise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `width: 800px`, which uses a fixed value (pixels), use a relative value, such as percentage. Try this:

```
.body-container  {
    display:flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #A8A8A8;
    width: 75%; /* ADJUSTED */
    height:250px;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot...that worked like charm. I have also changed the margin values to % and it is working now. :)

Comment: Using percentages for `width`, `margin` and other properties is pretty simple and straightforward. It gets a bit tricky when you use percentages for `height`. Here's what you need to know: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we need to have a responsive container, it is mandatory to specify width in **percentage**(%). Also make sure you take care of the elements within that container. Have correct break points and mention the width in percentage accordingly.